# How do I put data from Roman Nuriks Wizard Pager review into database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragmentactivity, wizard

Alright so I know this has been asked before but the question and answer both didn't help me in my situation. What I need to do is simply get all of the data from the review page at the end of the wizard and put it into my SQLite database so that I may use it in the future within my application.

I'm not even sure which class I should be working on in this case. I really hope someone who's had trouble with this before can help me because I've been searching for days and I'm stumped!

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

here is my what I've tried so far however it is always returning null

```
  mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mCurrentPageSequence.size()) {

                String title = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Post Title").getData().getString(SingleTextFieldPage.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                int price = mWizardModel.findByKey("Surf:Price").getData().getInt(NumberPage.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);  
                String maincat = mWizardModel.findByKey("Main Category").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);

                Long newId = myDb.insertRow(title, price, maincat);

                DialogFragment dg = new DialogFragment() {
                    @Override
                    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                .setMessage(R.string.submit_confirm_message)
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.submit_confirm_button, null)
                                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                                .create();
                    }
                };
                dg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "place_order_dialog");
            } else {
                if (mEditingAfterReview) {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                } else {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: As always, what did you try yourself? You can't expect people to answer such an open-ended question as this is, without even showing the least amount of effort in trying to make this work without help from others...

Comment: Yes sorry about that I've added some please take a look

Comment: Also I wouldn't be asking this specific of a question if I hadn't already tried 1000 times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Derek Smith I have figured out a way to save the data and it works for me.

This is my AbstractWizardModel class block:

```
@Override
protected PageList onNewRootPageList() {

    return new PageList(
            new LoginInfoPage(this, "Login Information").setRequired(true));
}
```

It is similar to the sample provided with Library.

Now in your MainActivity, write as below:

```
String data = mWizardModel.findByKey("LoginInformation").getData().getString(LoginInfoPage.EMAIL_DATA_KEY);
```

The main thing to retrieve data is "key". In my case, key is "Login Information" which is also your title.

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Comment: regaring your answer, do you know how to get data from a branch which is inside of another? 
Like the toast from the nurick's example. If you chose yes it will ask you for how long, i need to get that value, how long and i don't know how to...
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

This is hierarchy of quiz data entered:

Page List > Branch Page > Branch(Question) > Choice(Single or Multiple)

```
String data = mWizardModel.findByKey("Question:Choice").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
```

**Example**:

```
String data = mWizardModel.findByKey("Sandwich:Bread").getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
```

Also this is what i did to get all selected answers from Question and also to calculate score,

Inside

**mNextButton.setOnClickListener**

```
if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mCurrentPageSequence.size()) {
                    int score = 0;
                    String q1 = mWizardModel.findByKey("Yes:Question 1")
                            .getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                    String q2 = mWizardModel.findByKey("Yes:Question 2")
                            .getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                    String q3 = mWizardModel.findByKey("Yes:Question 3")
                            .getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                    String q4 = mWizardModel.findByKey("Yes:Question 4")
                            .getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                    String q5 = mWizardModel.findByKey("Yes:Question 5")
                            .getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                    String q6 = mWizardModel.findByKey("Yes:Question 6")
                            .getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                    String q7 = mWizardModel.findByKey("Yes:Question 7")
                            .getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                    String q8 = mWizardModel.findByKey("Yes:Question 8")
                            .getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                    String q9 = mWizardModel.findByKey("Yes:Question 9")
                            .getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
                    String q10 = mWizardModel.findByKey("Yes:Question 10")
                            .getData().getString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);

                    if (q1 == "c3") {
                        score = score + 1;
                    }
                    if (q2 == "c2") {
                        score = score + 1;
                    }
                    if (q3 == "c1") {
                        score = score + 1;
                    }
                    if (q4 == "c4") {
                        score = score + 1;
                    }
                    if (q5 == "c1") {
                        score = score + 1;
                    }
                    if (q6 == "c4") {
                        score = score + 1;
                    }
                    if (q7 == "c2") {
                        score = score + 1;
                    }
                    if (q8 == "c3") {
                        score = score + 1;
                    }
                    if (q9 == "c1") {
                        score = score + 1;
                    }
                    if (q10 == "c4") {
                        score = score + 1;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Score:" + score,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```