# How to get values from the Setup wizard

Tags: android, wizard

I am a beginner in android developing. I am building a simple app on android studio and I need a Setup Wizerd in my app. I did some search and found some answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718440/android-how-to-make-step-by-step-wizard) and I have found [this](https://github.com/TechFreak/WizardPager) library is good to make the setup wizard. I am using this library and initially the wizard is working.

Now, I need all the data I entered in the wizard at the finishing of it. But on the [sample project](https://github.com/TechFreak/WizardPager/tree/master/sample) of the library, at the end of the wizard it is not doing anything to get the data and do something with them. I did not find any help on this how to get the entered values at the end of the wizard. If someone can help me in this matter it will be very helpful. Thank you.

**EDIT:** I have found a similer problem with the solution here: [How do I put data from Roman Nuriks Wizard Pager review into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104469/how-do-i-put-data-from-roman-nuriks-wizard-pager-review-into-database?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read [Starting another activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) to learn how to pass data from one Activity to another. You should also read [Saving data](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) to learn about options for storing data more permanently.

Comment: I can save the data somewhere but at first I need to get them from the wizard. I am looking for a way to get all the data user selected like which radio button or which check box. The library is not using any fragment to show the radio buttons so I can not get the value in the usual way. This is what I am talking about: https://github.com/TechFreak/WizardPager/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/example/android/wizardpager/SandwichWizardModel.java

Comment: @BishwajyotiRoy Which part do you have trouble with? Do you know how to get the selection value of a RadioButton or CheckBox?

Comment: Yes I can get selection value if it is on a fragment or activity. What exactly I need is like this: [here](https://github.com/TechFreak/WizardPager/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/example/android/wizardpager/MainActivity.java) when the finish button is clicked: `mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mCurrentPageSequence.size()) { //here I need the values of buttons }`

Comment: @BishwajyotiRoy Please edit your question (or post a new one) to show what you are trying to do and what difficulties you are encountering in your attempts.

Comment: I have found a similar problem with the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104469/how-do-i-put-data-from-roman-nuriks-wizard-pager-review-into-database?rq=1  @Code-Apprentice thank you for your cooperation :)